# Ableton Live - record midi CC data during a live performance?

Tags: audio-recording, live, ableton-live

I'm really struggling with one little aspect of Live that has got me stumped. Suppose I've mapped a number of instrument parameters (LFOs, freq / filters, FX etc) to any number of dials, sliders or other MIDI controllers. As I'm laying down (live recording) the MIDI note data in Session View (ie: recording loops), I want to be able to modulate the parameters as well, in real-time; sometimes more than one parameter at a go. I'm finding that Ableton doesn't record the automation tracks until you go back and overdub.

This is clearly totally bogus, and I'm hoping I'm just missing something here.

The idea is to be able to improvise (and record the improvisation) with more than just the MIDI note data - I'd like my modulations to be recorded in real-time along with the note data that I'm performing. In short: capture the entire performance.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Midi CC data can be recorded one of two ways in Ableton.

1) Record the CC modulations while in Arrangement View. If you loop a section of the piece you're working on, you can fiddle with midi CC till the cows come home (so long as overdub is on (next to the transport controls)).

2) Program the CC modulations in the clips in the Session View.

One of Ableton's biggest shortcomings right now is that you cannot "jam" in the Arrangement view and copy those CC changes into the Session View into clips. There is plenty of discussion of that on the Ableton forums as well as some tutorials regarding your question.

Check http://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=162484&hilit=+record+automation for starters.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted this answer because it's basically saying that what I want to do cannot be done currently, which is a shame, but accurate. I"m not sure the link you posted was that useful (just some people ranting, but no real workaround), but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Ableton Live does this just fine. You'll just need to assign the MIDI controllers to the instrument/parameter you want to control(Ctrl+M), and then press record.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case.

Comment: Well, AL 3 does not have MIDI support. From AL 4 MIDI support is there. What does not work? When I record CC data, it adds it. When I record notes, they are overwritten.

Comment: Where / how are you recording CC data? I've edited my question to be more clear: I was talking about Session view. I realize that this was not mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Aha, session view is loop view? I'll try when I get back in the studio. I know it can be edited for sure though.